# What SynthConstants are supported by Component?

Tags: java, swing, synth

The [SynthConstants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/synth/SynthConstants.html) API says, "Constants used by Synth. Not all Components support all states." I have a question: What states in `SynthConstants` are respectively supported by each different Component? I think this is important for do a custom look and feel using Synth.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECTED` and `PRESSED` can be used with buttons, such as `JButtons` or other sub classes of `AbstractButton`, and not passive components like `JLabel`. The others are valid for pretty much all components.

Comment: all of event from SynthConstants are used by ButtonComponents, you can to simulating on Metal instance